# XLSX library with Angular

Tags: angular, xlsx

I'm using **XLSX** library to turn, in an Angular application, a HTML table into a XLS file.

I have no problem doing it, using the method **table_to_sheet**:

**XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(HTMLTableElement);**

The problem is that I want, in the generated xls file, the data not starting from the first row (A1), but for example, from the tenth row (A10); this because I have to add some rows of text 'programmatically' before showing the data retrieved from the HTML table.

I read documentation but I didn't find a solution; I don't even know if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#utility-functions).

There should be a function XLSX.utils.sheet_add_table(HTMLTableElement).

First create your sheet with

```
var sheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(HTMLTableElement table)
```

Then add your data at any point by specifying the origin in options parameter.

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_dom(sheet , [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]], {origin: "A2"});
```

or

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_dom(sheet , [[5,6,7], [6,7,8], [7,8,9]], {origin:{r:1, c:4}});
```

Comment: hi, I can't find the method sheet_add_table. Where did you find it?

Comment: Hello, I apologize, its sheet_add_dom not sheet_add_table. Please search for XLSX.utils.sheet_add_dom in the docs and you will get the idea. Editing my answer as well.